# Diagonal Scroll in React Native

Tags: react-native, scroll, diagonal

Does anyone have idea on how to scroll content diagonally in react-native?

```
<ScrollView>
  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
   ...
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

This one scrolls either horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally.